# Update device volume with Volume Keys in Unity Game Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, key, volume, google-cardboard

This is weird, but device volume control keys are not working in my Unity 3D Android Game. My game music plays on Media Stream of device and I simply want to increase/decrease Media stream volume of device with device volume keys (which works with other apps and games normally) in my Game.

P.s. I don't want to override any functionality of these keys, just do what they do. I'm using Unity v5.2.2f1 with Google Cardboard SDK v0.5.2.

Can someone please help me on this ? I've checked in google, unity forum, other blogs, but didn't find any answer. I also crosschecked my Platform settings.

Comment: Well, I just found out, that because I'm using Google Cardboard SDK, my volume keys are not working, as it disables those keys. But I really need to update music volume. Any other solution guys ??